# Two-sided limits using advanced algebra

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does $\frac{1-x}{x-1}=-1$?

This is part of a limits problem I am solving using algebra.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{1-x}{x-1} = \frac{-(-1+x)}{(x-1)} = \frac{-(x-1)}{(x-1)} = -1. $$

Answer (score 1):

$(1-x) = -x-(-1) = -(x-1)$.
Thus,
$\frac{(1-x)}{(x-1)} = \frac{-(x-1)}{(x-1)}$.

Now assuming that $x\neq 1$, this is defined and we can cancel the $(x-1)$ terms to get 
$\frac{-(x-1)}{(x-1)} = -\frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)}=-1.$